# std::exp of float negative infinity returns negative infinity for x64 builds in Visual C++ 2013

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Using `std::exp` to calculate `e^-infinity` returns `-infinity` when using the float representation of infinity and building an x64 binary using Visual C++ 2013. I would expect it to return 0, which is what happens with Win32 builds, or the version of `std::exp` that takes a `double`.

The following code, built as x64, demonstrates the issue.

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main(const int argc, const char** argv) {
    std::cout << "exp of float -infinity: " << std::exp(-std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "exp of double -infinity: " << std::exp(-std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()) << std::endl;
}
```

Command line options for compile (taken from Visual Studio):

```
/GS /Wall /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\vc120.pdb" /fp:precise /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Fp"x64\Release\NumericLimitsTest.pch"
```

Output of above:

```
exp of float -infinity: -1.#INF
exp of double -infinity: 0
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: This is a bug; it is fixed in the Visual C++ 2015 runtime libraries.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis - isn't this the definitive answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would normally say that was a bug of some description, since C++11 defers to C99 for `cmath` functionality and C99 clearly states in `F.9.3.1` that `exp(−∞) returns +0`. However, keep in mind that's in an annex of the standard which states:

> An implementation that defines `__STDC_IEC_559__` shall conform to the specifications in this annex.

That macro doesn't appear to be defined in either 32- or 64-bit mode in MSVC so it's probably *not* a bug and you may be out of luck. Nor does changing the floating point mode between `/fp:strict` and `/fp:precise` make things any better.

In all cases, the result seems to differ between 32-bit and 64-bit target and, based on the standard which only states that `exp` will `compute the base-e exponential of x` with seemingly no requirement on how, it seems to be okay.

---

If you're after a quick fix, using the `pow` function seems to generate the correct results:

```
#define DBL_E 2.71828182845904523536
#define FLT_E 2.71828182845904523536f
std::cout
    << "exp of float -infinity: "
    << std::pow(FLT_E, -std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity())
    << std::endl;
std::cout
    << "exp of double -infinity: "
    << std::pow(DBL_E,-std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity())
    << std::endl;
```

This generates zero for both lines regardless of whether you have `64-bit/32-bit`, `debug/release` or `fp:precise/fp:strict` but, whether that's guaranteed, I couldn't say.

Comment: Isn't the whole of Annex F optional?

Comment: @hvd, depends on whether MSVC defines `_ _STDC_IEC_559_ _`. I don't have it installed locally so cannot check. I'll update the answer.

Comment: score++ this might indeed be a strict/precise issue.

Comment: As of _cl_ version 18.00.31010 (VS 2013) the predefined macro `__STD_IEC_559__` isn't defined. Moreover, VC++ is know for its C99 non-conformance :)